# dataset with bulk changes

Tags: asp.net

i have an  dataset around 1000 records in it. i have  made  changes around 50 rows in dataset,
i have created an new

```
dataset dsnew=   ds.GetChanges();
```

now this dsNew would contain all the new  50  rows which we made changes, now i  want to update these  values to Database,

here i do not want to call  5o times  my update command or stored procdure to update my values  to table which would really decrease the performance

is there any better way to solve it.

Thanks Prince

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/212571/add-a-feature-to-be-able-to-do-bulk-update) age old request to MS, but still you can try for following options,

1. ADO.Net [batch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810297.aspx) update.

Note : For insertion you can use [SQL Bulk Copy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx),